# iOS - Scrolling two UITextViews simultaneously

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, uitextview

I've done some looking around but I haven't been able to find anything that clearly explains how I could simultaneously scroll two un-editable UITextViews. I think I may need to use either `scrollRangeToVisible`, or `setContentOffset`, though I could not get either of them to work.

Does anyone have any examples/samples, or documentation regarding this that they could point me towards?

EDIT: To clarify, I would like to be able to scroll one UITextView, and have the changes as a result of the scrolling reflected on a second UITextView as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React in

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
```

and set the other's scrollView `setContentVisible` according to `scrollView.contentOffset`.

Just be aware that some methods of `UIScrollView` will invoke `scrollViewDidScroll` even if called programmatically. This applies to scrollRangeToVisible and will end up in a loop unless you take action to prevent this loop. I don't think that `setContentOffset` or setting `scrollView2.contentOffset = CGPointMake(..,..)` does call `scrollViewDidScroll`. However, I would not sign this in blood. Be prepared to see a loop and take actions to avoid it. (such as boolean instance variable set before calling `setContentOffset` and re-set in `scrollViewDidScroll` followed by `return;`)

Comment: Hmmm, maybe im misunderstanding what you mean, but let me clarify what I'm trying to achieve. What I would like to happen is to be able to scroll the content of one UITextView and have a second UITextView respond to the scrolling as well. I think with the UIScrollView I would be scrolling both of them without changing their content view, if I understand correctly.

Comment: All right. I had given two answers at once because I was not sure, what you wanted. Answer edited accordingly. You will have to use two scroll views. In the first you need to react when it is scrolled and then programatically scroll the other one to the same extend (offset). Just avoid a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use the UIScrollViewDelegate methods to get information about scroll actions of the first scroll view and then scroll the second programmatically like that:

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)view1 {
    scrollView2.contentOffset = view1.contentOffset;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just continuing with previous answers, to give some more information, I generated this code:

In the interface (.h):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DoubleTextViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textView1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textView1;

@end
```

In your implementation (.m):

Use this `viewDidLoad` function after defining the corresponding properties and global variables.

```
#import "DoubleTextViewController.h"

#define TEXT_VIEW_1_TAG 1001
#define TEXT_VIEW_2_TAG 1002

@interface DoubleTextViewController () {

    BOOL isScrolling;
}

@end

@implementation DoubleTextViewController

@synthesize textView1, textView2;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view..

    isScrolling = NO;

    [self.textView1 setTag:TEXT_VIEW_1_TAG];
    [self.textView2 setTag:TEXT_VIEW_2_TAG];

    [self.textView1 setDelegate:self];
    [self.textView2 setDelegate:self];
}
```

And add this function for simultaneous scroll.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    if (isScrolling) {
        return;
    }


    isScrolling = YES;

    if (scrollView.tag == TEXT_VIEW_1_TAG) {

        [self.textView2 setContentOffset:scrollView.contentOffset animated:NO];

    } else if (scrollView.tag == TEXT_VIEW_2_TAG) {

        [self.textView1 setContentOffset:scrollView.contentOffset animated:NO];
    }

    isScrolling = NO;
}
```

As proposed by Hermann Klecker, the `isScrolling` variable stops scrolling loops and makes the user experience nicer. Using the code proposed by Fabian Kreiser makes the scroll stops as soon as the user leaves the finger, making it strange.